# Prove that $\int f\,d\mu>0 \text{ if and only if } \mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})>0.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I am having a particularly difficult time *starting* the following problem

> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S}, \mu)$ is a measure space and $f:X\rightarrow
> > [0,\infty]$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.  Prove that
>   $$\int f\,d\mu>0 \text{ if and only if } \mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})>0.$$

For a measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty]$, my textbook defines $\int fd\mu$ as $$\sup\left\{\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\mu(A_k):  \sum_{k=1}^m a_k \chi_{A_k}\leq f, \text{ where } m\in\mathbf{Z}^+, a_1,\ldots, a_m\geq 0 \text{ and } A_1,\ldots, A_m\in\mathcal{S}\right\}.$$  Thus I know for the $\implies$ direction, I have that this $\sup>0$.  I see that this $\sup$ is taken over the set of certain sums of  measures of subsets of $X$.  I just don't know how to draw a connection with this and the condition I want to prove, that being $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})>0.$  For the $\impliedby$ direction, I am just as lost, but I think understanding the first direction could make the converse easier for me to understand.

So, could any of you provide me with a hint, or maybe help me understand in a more intuitive way what this question is asking?  I would really appreciate it!

Edit:  I do believe it is assumed that $f$ is a nonnegative function.

Comment: (PS since $f$ maps into $[0,\infty]$, it is non-negative, confirming your belief in the edit)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Great observation!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Assume that $0\le a_k\chi_{A_k}\le f.$ Then we have that

$$a_k\mu(A_k)\le a_k\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\}).$$

What do you get if $a_k>0$ and $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})\le 0?$

Comment: Can I ask how you knew that $a_k\mu(A_k)\le a_k\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})$?  Sorry, I'm not good at this stuff at all...

Comment: If   $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})\le 0$ $f>0$ and $a_k\chi_{A_k}\le f$ then $a_k\mu(A_k)\le a_k\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})\le 0$ which shows that $a_k=0$ or $\mu(A_k)=0.$ From that we get that $f=0.$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Conversely, assume that $\int f=0.$ Then $\sup=0$ from where $a_k\mu(A_k)= 0.$ If $a_k>0$ it is $\mu(A_k)= 0.$ That is $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>a_k\})=0.$ And $a_k>0$ can be any positive real number.

Answer (score 1):

By Tonelli's theorem,
$$ \int_X f d\mu = \int_X\int_0^f d\lambda \ d\mu =\iint_{X\times[0,\infty]} \chi_{\{x,t: f(x)>t\}} d(\mu\otimes \lambda) = \int_0^\infty \mu(f>t) \ d\lambda(t),$$
where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$.
if $LHS>0$ then $RHS>0$ so that there is at least one $t$ for which $\mu(f>t) > 0$. This is decreasing in $t$ since the sets $\{f>t\} = f^{-1}((t,\infty))$ and $(t,\infty)$ are nested. Thus $\mu(f>0) \ge \mu (f>t)>0$. A similar(but not exactly the same!) idea also works for the converse.

---

Judging by the content of your post, you don't yet know the proof of Tonelli's theorem to justify the exchange of integrals above...but IMO this integral identity gives good intuition.

Comment: An answer too advanced for the likes of me, but I appreciate the alternative approach nonetheless!

Comment: @ThyArtisMath yes well I came up with this before trying to use something like markov's inequality. You can at least formally interchange integrals to appreciate the proof :)